# In Java where do I put my sprite files to make this open source code work?

Tags: java, eclipse, sprite, gif

I am a beginner and I am trying to learn by messing around with some open source game code.
I was setting it all up in Eclipse but I don't know where to put these sprite `gif` files.

In the code I found this:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(ref);
```

And when I put all the class files under a java project together and tried to run I got this error message:

> Can't find ref: sprites/ship.gif

Of course the code came with sprites including `ship.gif`. I just don't know where to put it. I tried making a folder under the `java` project called sprites and putting it in there.
I don't have a res folder.

Answer (score 1):

The `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource` method look for relative path of the data from the package of the class. 
Assuming your class is `com.my.package.MyClass`, you usually have your project organized containing at least in your case:

- `com/my/package/MyClass.java`
- `com/my/package/sprites/ship.gif`

Most of the time, you certainly have a `resources` or a `images` folder for your java project.

Answer (score 0):

You can only load those resources if they are on the classpath. Try to add the `sprites` folder as a source folder on your Eclipse build path and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Put the .gif in the jar.

This can be achieved by creating dedicated folder you add in the sources of eclipse. Often this folder is called "resources".

Be ware that in some cases a "/" is required at the begining of ref.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.

How I fixed my problem:

When I downloaded the source I opened folders and went to the class files and copied them to my project and then I was trying to do the same thing with the sprites. What I didn't realize is that if I just drop the two main folders "org" and "sprites" into the source file of my project then it all works on its own. These two folders were the first things I had after downloading this open source code.